# Inherits the color of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some topics with different colors

I want the border div "ItemListHeader" inherits the color of another div "color1" which is not parent(structure HTML bellow)  Possible with css or js?
Thank you,

```css
#color1{
    background-color: rgba(11, 114, 180, 1);
}
#color2{
    background-color: rgba(1, 14, 18, 0);
}
.ItemListHeader{
border-right: 30px solid (inherit);
}
```

```html
<div class="List">
<ul class="Menu">
    <li class="topic1">
        <div  id="color1" class="ColorBaseTopics"></div>
            <ul class="SubTopic1">
                <li>
                    <div class="ItemListHeader">
                    
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
      <li class="topic2">
        <div  id="color2" class="ColorBaseTopics"></div>
            <ul class="SubTopic2">
                <li>
                    <div class="ItemListHeader">
                    
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why not give the color a class name, and add to both element?

Comment: Here, in CSS you declare color1 as CLASS and use it in div as ID. it will not apply color in first div also

Comment: @DanielH because he wants to "copy" the background color to the border

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with [sass variables](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_)

or, as others have mentioned, by giving the two objects the same class

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which allow you to compose CSS at a higher level of abstraction .

Less calls these "Mixins"

Instead of

```
/* CSS */
#header {
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#footer {
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

You could say

```
/* LESS */
.rounded_corners {
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#header {
  .rounded_corners;
}

#footer {
  .rounded_corners;
}
```